# Как проверить доступность страницы сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть каталог сайтов, где пользователи добавляют свои сайты (скриншот, название, описание и так далее) но со временем не которые сайты перестают работать и администратору нужно проверить, какие сайты работают а какие нет. (я понимаю можно каждую ссылку открывать в браузере, но сайтов много и это не удобно) хочу сделать кнопку, напротив каждого сайта и при клике проверять работает данная страница сайта или нет.

Как можно проверить на `php` или `js` доступность страница сайта ?

```
if($page_url = 1 ){  
        echo "Страница работает";
    } else {  
        echo "Страница сайта не работает !!!";      
    }
```

Comment: Можно получить [header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php) от сайта и по статус-коду определить существование страницы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если проверять очень простым способом, можно попробовать что-то загружать с сайта, если загрузка успешная значит сайт работает. Например можно загружать `title`.

```
 function getTitle($url) {
    if(!$url) return ;
    $title="";
    @$page=file_get_contents($url); 
    if ($page) {
      if (preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~iu", $page, $out)) {
        $title = $out[1];   
      }
    }
    return $title;
  }
```

Проверка:

```
$page_title = getTitle('http://www.site.com/news/index.html');

if($page_title){ 
    echo "Страница работает";  
} else {  
    echo "Страница не работает";        
}
```

Вот еще один пример на cURL:

```
       //возвращает true, если домен доступен, false если нет
   function isDomainAvailible($domain)
   {
       //проверка на валидность урла
       if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
               return false;
       }
       //инициализация curl
       $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
       curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
       curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
       curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
       curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
       //получение ответа
       $response = curl_exec($curlInit);
       curl_close($curlInit);
       if ($response) return true;
       return false;
   }
```

Проверка на cURL:

```
if (isDomainAvailible('http://www.site.com/news/index.html')){
       echo "Домен доступен!";
   } else {
     echo "Упс, домен не доступен.";
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

/* ============================================
    Проверка доступности URL
============================================ */
function sendUrl($url) {
    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($response) {
            return $response;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $content = @file_get_contents($url);
        if ($content === false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    }
}

//$url = sendUrl('http://www.sadasdasd213.kz/'); // Не рабочий сайт
$url = sendUrl('https://batas.kz/'); // Рабочий сайт
if ($url) {
    echo $url;
} else {
    echo 'Страница сайта не работает.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какаую проверку Вы хотите сделать. Если просто отвечает сервер или нет - это одно. Послать обычный запрос и ждать ответа...
А вот если нужна проверка по содержанию, то тут сложнее, и скорее всегол без контроля не обойтись...

Можно сделать ajax вызов на страницу сайта. Если в результате пришел разумный HTML код, значит страница жива.

Однако, что если сайт хостился на shared сервисе, и был закрыт. В таком случае обычно хостинги вешают свои страницы типа "Сайт закрыт". А это реальный HTML. и следовательно он пройдет проверку...

В реале вы можете лишь проверить отвечает ли сервер на запрос. Но содержимое сайта надо проверять вручную...